# Problem with HAproxy and Keycloak on the same machine

Tags: java, keycloak, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have an instance of Keycloak(15.0.2) and a HAproxy on the same machine (IP=10.0.0.) and 2 other instances of Keycloak on another machine (10.0.0.2).
Both of the Keycloak instances are configured by standalone-ha.xml.
My haproxy.cfg in like below:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log stdout format raw local0
    maxconn     4000

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option                  http-server-close
    option                  forwardfor       
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend http_web 
    bind 10.0.0.1:80
    mode http
    default_backend Keycloak
    option httplog
    option logasap

backend Keycloak
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    server  keycloak1 10.0.0.1:8080 check
    server  keycloak2 10.0.0.2:8080 check
    server  keycloak3 10.0.0.2:8180 check
```

When I run my HAproxy, the Keycloak instance on 10.0.0.1 (same machine with HAproxy) suspend with the below warnings:

**WARN**  **[org.xnio.nio]** **(default Accept)** **XNIO008001:** **Socket** **accept** **failed,** **backing** **off** **for** **250** **milliseconds:** **java.net.SocketException:** **Invalid** **argument**

**WARN**  **[org.jboss.modcluster]** **(ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)** **MODCLUSTER000033:** **Failed** **to** **interrupt** **socket** **reception.:** **java.io.IOException:** **Can't** **assign** **requested** **address**

So that the server runs on 10.0.0.1:80 (HAproxy) will not work properly. The below line shows the HAproxy logs:

10.0.0.1:21703 [12:59:24.338] http_web http_web/ -1/-1/-1/-1/+10002 408 +0 - - cR-- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 ""

10.0.0.1:21703 [12:59:24.338] http_web http_web/ -1/-1/-1/-1/+10002 408 +0 - - cR-- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 ""

And when I stop the 10.0.0.1 Keycloak instance the other 2 instances work properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

look at your front-end configuration. The line "default_backend" seems to refer to an undefined backend. Try to fix it with a valid back-end name

Comment: Sorry It was a typing mistake. I changed the default_backend but my problem is not solved yet.